# SQL Insert statement where single value selects from another table

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Invite VALUES (NULL,?,(SELECT id FROM User WHERE name = ?),?);
```

However this doesnt seem to work.

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

**Update**

The following php code gives me erro code 1136:

```
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO Invite SELECT NULL, ?, id, ? FROM User WHERE username = ?';
$variables = array($team_id,$_SESSION['User']['id'],$username);
$result = $this->db->prepTemplate($sql, 'iis', $variables);
```

Comment: code 1136 clearly mention error "Column count doesn't match value count". Check the number of columns in table Invite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Invite 
SELECT NULL, ?, id, ?
FROM User
WHERE name = ?
```

Comment: i cannot get the following to work: INSERT INTO Invite SELECT NULL, ?, id, ? FROM User WHERE username = ?